# What technology : painting program in browser?

Tags: html, svg, cloud, paint

I wanna develop a little paint-program (SVG business-card designer) which should be hosted in the cloud, im trying to get my head around what technology i should settle on.

Possible answers as i see it would be SilverLight, Flash, Java, HTML5.

I would be happy to avoid SilverLight and Flash for several reasons, HTML5 im worried about due to compatibillity with ex. IE browser ? Java i dont know enough about to understand if that would be the right way.

One example im quite impressed about is :

http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

And looking to somewhat hit the same as that, but again IE explorer ( which is what majority uses ) is an issue here too regarding SVG format.

I might be able to live with only ex. IE9, but wondering what you guys would think would be the right approach/language/framework/technology to make such an application ?

Thanks alot.

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10300498/472495) may be of interest, using server-side SVG. It's slower than client-side stuff, but avoids the browser compatibility issues you refer to. That said, RaphaelJS looks great for the client side, and if you don't have demanding requirements regarding text wrapping on a path or in a shape, that would be worth trialling.

Answer (score 1):

For a business card designer, you should be concentrating on font and page layout, in which case you need to use an online editor. There are lots of free WYSIWYG editirors that run from web pages and there are soe very sophisticated ones like FCKeditor. FCK also includes everything that you need for uploading images and maintaining a clipart gallery. I beleieve that it's available for both Windows and Apache web servers and it doesn't require admin permission to install, once the upload folders have write permissions.